# friendly_id and ActiveScaffold conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold, friendly-id

I have [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and [ActiveScaffold](http://activescaffold.com/) installed for my Rails application.

Because not all of my models have unique name fields I have to use the [Slugged Model](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#slugged_models) to make it work. friendly_id does the job flawlessly I have friendly URLs and I can load the objects using the friendly id.

But when I want to create a new object with ActiveScaffold, it says the following error message:

> ActiveScaffold::ReverseAssociationRequired
>   (Association slugs: In order to
>   support :has_one and :has_many where
>   the parent record is new and the child
>   record(s) validate the presence of the
>   parent, ActiveScaffold requires the
>   reverse association (the belongs_to).)

Of course I cannot create the `belongs_to` association in that side because it's created by the `friendly_id` module and every model which works slugged way should be included there.

The model looks like this:

```
class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true, :approximate_ascii => true
end
```

In my `ApplicationController`:

```
class Admin::FooBarsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  active_scaffold :foo_bar do |config|
    config.list.columns = [ :id, :name ])
    config.update.columns = [ :name ]
    config.create.columns = config.update.columns
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make this work?

The versions: friendly_id `3.2.0`, ActiveScaffold latest in the `rails-2.3` git branch.

**UPDATE**: Seems like it does not conflict in production mode.

Comment: maybe not relevant but , are you using  globalize2  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling

```
has_friendly_id :name, :cache_column => 'cached_slug', :use_slug => true
```

... creates a has_many and a has one associations pointing to a slug AR model which hasn't any polymorphic belongs to association properly defined.

So basically what you need to do to solve this error is to define the reverse associations in the controller of your parent model (the one who has friendly_id stuff)

```
  active_scaffold :products do |config|
    ...
    config.columns[:slug].association.reverse = :product
    config.columns[:slugs].association.reverse = :product
  end
```

and it works :-)

PS : I use friendly_id as gem and ActiveScaffold VHO master branch for rails 3

Comment: @nicolas, you're a genius, greatly appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have the same problem , i have solved , but i dont remember my solution , lookin at my code the only relevant hack is to use friendly_id as plugin and load it at last with config.plugin in environemnt.rb

```
aviable_plugins = Dir.glob(RAILS_ROOT+"/vendor/plugins/*").collect {|i| i.split("/").last }
config.plugins  = aviable_plugins + [:friendly_id] #friendly_id must be last
```

I'M NOT SURE ,sorry, but if you try let my know.

sorry for my english to

Comment: I'll try but as the `environment.rb` says the default order is alphabetical, so `activescaffold` will be before `friendly_id` in any way. :(

Comment: It's a bit complicated because I'm using a lot of plugins. So I will try in a clean install.

Comment: My project is using friendly_id 3.1.3 and Active Scaffold 1.2RC1.

Comment: I've tested with a clean install, just the `active_scaffold` and the `friendly_id` plugin was installed in the `vendor/plugin` directory and no luck, still the same problem.